# Java AWS Lambda "ErrorMessage: Class not found

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-lambda

I'm trying to write a simple java lambda function. However I keep receiving this error when I run the lambda test after uploading the jar file for the lambda function:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Class not found: org.example.HelloWorld.handler",
  "errorType": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"
}
```

Here is the Java code for the lambda:

```
package org.example;

/**
* Hello world!
*
*/
public class HelloWorld
{
    public String handler() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

For some more context this is a maven project, and I'm creating the jar file by running `mvn clean package` from the root `LambdaExample` directory.

Here is my file/directory structure for the project including the `hello-lambda.jar` that gets uploaded to AWS lambda .
[image]

Here is my lambda function handler:
[image]

Here is the lambda function summary:
[image]

And here is full error output from AWS Lambda Test:
[image]

This seems like a pretty basic project and I followed a tutorial ([this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-ejay6w2As&ab_channel=AjayWadhara)) so it should work. Anyone know why I'm getting this error and how I can fix it?

Comment: Or configure the [handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler.html) method e.g. `org.example.HelloWorld::handler`.

Comment: Your handler should be something like `org.example.HelloWorld::handler`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a typo while specifying the handler in the runtime settings. The correct way to specify the handler is:

`packageName.className::method`

In your case, instead of:

`org.example.HelloWorld.handler`

Change to:

`org.example.HelloWorld::handler`